# Three JS - Scaling texture to fit a (any size) Plane perfectly

Tags: three.js

In essence, I want to replicate the behaviour of how the CSS, `background-size: cover` works.

Looking here you can see the image is being scaled keeping its aspect ratio, but it's not really working correctly, as the image does not fill the Plane, leaving margins either side - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/8650f9Ji6qWffTqE?preview

Code snippet (Lines 170 - 175) -

```
var geometryAspectRatio = 5/3;
var imageAspectRatio = 3264/2448;
textTile.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
textTile.repeat.x = geometryAspectRatio / imageAspectRatio; 
textTile.offset.x = 0.5 * ( 1 - textTile.repeat.x );
```

What I want to happen is for it so scale-up and then reposition its self in the centre (much how `cover` works).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var repeatX, repeatY;
repeatX = w * this.textureHeight / (h * this.textureWidth);
if (repeatX > 1) {
  //fill the width and adjust the height accordingly
  repeatX = 1;
  repeatY = h * this.textureWidth / (w * this.textureHeight);
  mat.map.repeat.set(repeatX, repeatY);
  mat.map.offset.y = (repeatY - 1) / 2 * -1;
} else {
  //fill the height and adjust the width accordingly
  repeatX = w * this.textureHeight / (h * this.textureWidth);
  repeatY = 1;
  mat.map.repeat.set(repeatX, repeatY);
  mat.map.offset.x = (repeatX - 1) / 2 * -1;
}
```

Updated https://next.plnkr.co/edit/LUk37xLG2yvv6hgg?preview

Answer (score 0):

For anyone confused by this as I was, the missing piece for me is that .repeat.x and .repeat.y properties of any texture can be values less than one, and scales up the image when is under 1 as the inverse of the scale.  Think about it, when it's scale 2, in a way it repeats .5 times because you only see half of the image.

So...
Something not supported by textures in THREE.js and common in some libraries, would be

`.scaleX = 2;` (not supported in THREE.js textures as of v1.30.1)

And the THREE.js texture equivalent would be

`texture.repeat.x = .5;`

To convert scale to "repeat", simply do the inverse of the scale

```
var desiredScaleX = 3;
var desiredRepeatX = 1 / desiredScaleX;
```

The repeat for scale 3 comes out to (1/3) = .3333;  In other words a 3x image would be cropped and only show 1/3 of the image, so it repeats .3333 times.

As for scaling to fit to cover, generally choosing the larger scale of the two will do the trick, something like:

```
var fitScaleX = targetWidth / actualWidth;
var fitScaleY = targetHeight / actualHeight;
var fitCoverScale = Math.max(fitScaleX,fitScaleY);
var repeatX = 1 / fitCoverScale;
var repeatY = 1 / fitCoverScale;
```